# Wrong orientation of a contour plot in Python using Matplotlib's contourf()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am a beginner in Python and I'll try to visualize a function depending on x and y. With the contour plot the maximum should be seen easier.

That is my code and the output. The question comes below.

```
# Generate synthetic plot 
x_fine=np.linspace(-4,10,100).reshape(-1,1)
y_fine=np.linspace(-3,3,100)

f_xy=1.5*np.sin(x_fine) - 0.1*(x_fine-3)**2 +10 - 0.5*(y_fine**2-2) + np.sin(y_fine)*2
#f_xy= -(x_fine-2)**2 - (y_fine)**2 +20


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(x_fine, y_fine, f_xy, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False, alpha=0.6)
                      

ax.contourf(x_fine.flatten(),y_fine, f_xy, zdir='z', offset=-0, cmap=cm.coolwarm,alpha=0.7)

ax.set_xlabel("$x$")
ax.set_ylabel("$y$")
ax.set_zlabel("Objective")

plt.show()
```

[image: Outcoming plot]

So, if you might see, the plot contour plot reveals the contours, but somehow rotated by 90 degrees. If I just change the x and y input in the contour plot method, the graphs deforms. If I change the x and y input both in the contour plot and in the plot_surface command, the graph is shown correctly. But then, I need declare my x-axis as "y" and vice versa, which I would like to avoid.

I hope I made my problem clear. I am interested in reading your answers what I might have done wrong or why the code behaves as is behaves :D

Comment: As I explain in my answer below, the issue stems from numpy, so it might be worth  adding numpy to  the tags on this question so that other people can find it easier in future :)

Answer (score 1):

In numpy, the axes are ordered row-column, e.g.

```
a = np.zeros((3, 2))
a
>>> [[0, 0],
     [0, 0],
     [0, 0]]
```

When you reshape `x_fine` to `(-1, 1)` you give it a width of 1 and a height of N. Something like.

```
x_fine
>> [[-4],
    [-3.96],
    ...
    [10]]
```

Following the convention of x across and y up/down, this is the wrong orientation.

Put the `reshap(-1, 1)` on `y_fine` instead. Then when you draw the contours call `flatten()` on `y_fine` instead of `x_fine`.

Now the two plots are orientated the same. If you want to verify that they are rotated correctly, and not BOTH off by 90 degrees, set f_xy to something simple like `f_xy = x_fine + np.zeros_like(y_fine)` and you'll see both increasing in the `x` direction.